# Can't assign anonymous delegate to signed delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-delegates

I am looking for a way to assign different delegates in a list to `MethodInfo`'s without having information about the return types beforehand. Below is the code code I am using. The comments give additional information on what is happening. It is a lengthy bit of code but I have reduced it as much as I can.

**Main Snippet**

```
private const string methodName = "Execute";

    public static void Main()
    {
        ExampleClass1 e1 = new ExampleClass1();
        ExampleClass2 e2 = new ExampleClass2();
        ExampleClass3 e3 = new ExampleClass3();

        /* Code below Simulates:  "e3.GetString = e2.Execute;" */
        var method = e2.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

        for (int i = 0; i < e3.DelegateList.Count; i++)
        {
            // First check the type of e2 return
            Type methodType = method.ReturnType;

            // Check that its the same return type as delegate
            if (methodType != e3.DelegateList[i].ReturnType)
                continue;

            // Assign delegate to method
            var returnType = e3.DelegateList[i].DelegateType;
            e3.DelegateList[i].Delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(returnType, e2, method);

            /* Code below only for debugging */
            Console.WriteLine("The delegate in the list: " + e3.DelegateList[i].Delegate);// Returns Type of StringHandler
            Console.WriteLine("The delegate in the object: " + e3.GetString);// Returns null
            e3.GetString = e3.DelegateList[i].Delegate;// This throws Error Cannot convert Delegate to StringHandler
        }

        /* Code above Simulates:  "e3.GetString = e2.Execute;" */

        e2.GetNumber = e1.Execute;

        e3.Execute();// Throws Null References Exception on

        // Read the key
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**Supporting Classes/Code**

If you need more information about supporting classes, please see the code below. In addition, this is a self-contained program and should be runnable as is.

```
 public class ExampleClass3
{
    public delegate string StringHandler();

    public delegate int IntHandler();

    public StringHandler GetString { get; set; }
    public IntHandler GetInt { get; set; }

    public List<DelegateInfo<Type, Type, Delegate>> DelegateList { get; set; }

    public ExampleClass3()
    {
        DelegateList = new List<DelegateInfo<Type, Type, Delegate>>();
        DelegateList.Add(new DelegateInfo<Type, Type, Delegate>(typeof(StringHandler), typeof(string), GetString));
        DelegateList.Add(new DelegateInfo<Type, Type, Delegate>(typeof(IntHandler), typeof(int), GetInt));
    }

    public object Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetString());

        return null;
    }
}

public class ExampleClass2
{
    public delegate int NumberHandler();

    public NumberHandler GetNumber { get; set; }

    public string Execute() => $"Your Number Is {GetNumber()}";
}

public class ExampleClass1
{
    public int number = 5;

    public int Execute() => number;
}

public class DelegateInfo<T1, T2, T3>
{
    public DelegateInfo(T1 delegateType, T2 returnType, T3 @delegate)
    {
        DelegateType = delegateType;
        ReturnType = returnType;
        Delegate = @delegate;
    }

    public T1 DelegateType { get; set; }
    public T2 ReturnType { get; set; }
    public T3 Delegate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You either need to make an awful type check and cast the value or change how you're doing this completely. For example, something like the visitor pattern might work quite nicely here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code a bit to demonstrate how I would go about this. First off, don't create a special DelegateInfo class - stick with the standard .NET reflection library as much as possible. They did a really good job on it - but it does take a while to learn.

Here is the code:

```
    private const string methodName = "Execute";

    public static void Main()
    {
        ExampleClass1 e1 = new ExampleClass1();
        ExampleClass2 e2 = new ExampleClass2();
        ExampleClass3 e3 = new ExampleClass3();

        /* Code below Simulates:  "e3.GetString = e2.Execute;" */
        var method = e2.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);            
        Type methodType = method.ReturnType;

        // Create a Func<T> that will invoke the target method            
        var funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(methodType);
        var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcType, e2, method);

        var properties = e3.GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {              
            if (properties[i].PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(funcType)) {
                properties[i].SetValue(e3, del );
            }
        }

        /* Code above Simulates:  "e3.GetString = e2.Execute;" */

        e2.GetNumber = e1.Execute;

        e3.Execute();

        // Read the key
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public class ExampleClass3
    {         
        public Func<String> GetString { get; set; }
        public Func<int> GetInt { get; set; }

        public ExampleClass3()
        { }

        public object Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ExampleClass2
    {
        public Func<int> GetNumber { get; set; }

        public string Execute() => $"Your Number Is {GetNumber()}";
    }

    public class ExampleClass1
    {
        public int number = 5;

        public int Execute() => number;
    }
```

First off, note how I got rid of the custom delegate definitions in favor of Func. This will prove much easier to work with in a generic fashion. Note how ExampleClass3 is defined now:

```
    public class ExampleClass3
    {         
        public Func<String> GetString { get; set; }
        public Func<int> GetInt { get; set; }

        public ExampleClass3()
        { }

        public object Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I can use the fact that all these functions are of type Func to develop a generic solution to assigning them a value. Based upon the return type of the target method, I can construct a Func delegate of the appropriate type (and link it to the specific e2 instance in question):

```
    var funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(methodType);
    var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcType, e2, method);
```

Now I can directly assign this delegate as the value of any properties with a matching delegate type:

```
        var properties = e3.GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {              
            if (properties[i].PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(funcType)) {
                properties[i].SetValue(e3, del );
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: While this works, you're removing any strict compile time type checking by using reflection.

Comment: @DavidG Yes you are doing some run-time type checking when automatically assigning the Func<T> references. That's not necessarily a bad thing,especially if its a one-time setup routine. In this case I don't know if it is appropriate or not since the OP hasn't elaborated on what they are trying to use this for exactly. I was simply showing him how he could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is a cast missing:

```
e3.GetString = (ExampleClass3.StringHandler)e3.DelegateList[i].Delegate;
```

Comment: Hi Klaus, unfortunately, that won't work because of two reasons. 1. I should have made it more clear but I won't have the actual method name. 2. I won't know the cast type. I have it here because I made it purposefully made the snippet for StackOverflow so people can run it.

If I do do it your way it would have to be `(e3.DelegateList[i].DelegateType)` or using the `typeof` or `GetType` methods. But they throw errors themselves.